# What other node to fix on the rim

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have new basic nodes. I want it on the rim.

[image]

[image]

I can see the preview but cant fix on the rim.

[image]

I have uv the mesh but did not get any solution. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You have the texture coordinate set to UV, but the object doesn't seem to be UV unwrapped. Regardless, *generated* or *object* are the conventions for procedural textures. I also find that a wave texture works better than a gradient. Lastly, you must be in Lookdev or Rendered mode to see it.

[image: Textures]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot. side its working on the top (arrow head) its not working. https://imgur.com/a/poph4is

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm not sure how to deform the pattern to make it "follow the path" so to speak. You might have to UV unwrap the top section using "follow active quads" so it becomes one straight line that you can then put a gradient or a wave through.

Answer (score 0):

If you play around with the color ramp (for example, by changing one of the colors to green and then sliding the values around), you'll see that it works when the second slider is really close to the first one, which means that the texture is too big.  Try adjusting the mapping node to have a scale of 10 or 20, for example, and then playing with the location values to move it into the right location.